# Given a 3-dimensional coordinate system A, what is the rotation matrix so that the 3-dimensional coordinate system B has the same orientation as A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

The result I am trying to prove is

Given a 3-dimensional coordinate system A, what is the rotation matrix so that the 3-dimensional coordinate system B has the same orientation as A?

I am able to derive the rotation matrices when both coordinate systems share one axis, i.e. rotation along the x,y and z axes. I wonder if it is possible to use this result to derive the prior problem

Comment: A rotation matrix does not change the orientation of a coordinate system.

Comment: Make a first rotation about $x_A$ or $y_A$ axis, to align $z_B$ parallel to $z_A$. After that you know how to proceed.

Comment: How do I know that this method will result in all possible rotations